# Can I fix my "broken" hard drive (temporarily) ? Ticking hard drive plates issue

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, backup, hardware-failure

My hard drive isn't working anymore... :-(

It is a storage only NTFS partitionned HDD. It contains movies, series and games backups. When I mount it (on a linux distro), it's showing me the folders at the root of the disk but I'm unable to `ls` a folder containing subfolders with all my movies (for kodi).

It has been working for a "long" time (+4 years) and then suddenly it won't read/open my movies anymore. To check what wasn't working, I connected using SSH and tried to `ls` my movies directory. I got the following error:

```
ls: cannot access xxxxxxxxxx: Input/output error
```

After a few googling, it seemed like it's an hardware related issue. And indeed, the harddrive was producing a strange `tick tick tick` sound from time to time.

I opened the hard drive and I saw that the read plate can't turn around normally. It's moving clockwise by steps.

I'm sure I'll need a new HDD but I'd like to find some way to copy my data before putting it in the trash. So here are my questions:
    * Is it a known issue ?
    * Is there some way to fix it ?

Here is a video recording of what's going inside:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zuell9fhrahrcdv-JkMvAMWYxyEL1_pl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: "I opened the hard drive and I saw that the read plate can't turn around normally" - By doing this, you've permanently destined the drive to the scrap heap. SFAIK hard drives are vacuum sealed to maintain the gap between the platters and the read/write heads. You might as well throw it in the trash. "Is it a known issue ?" - Yes, hard drives aren't immortal. If you want to get the data off and money isn't an issue, there are plenty of data recovery experts, but I suspect your out of luck there too now, having opened the drive up.

Comment: @spikey_richie, not quite right. You will see that hard drives have a small (fitlered) hole in them. These are to help maintain an equal air pressure between the exterior and interior of the drive. Hence, there isn't a vacuum inside the housing. Either way, I have no doubt the drive is now hosed.

Answer (score 0):

> I opened the hard drive...

Your hard drive, whilst previously 'merely' terminally ill, died at that moment.

Your only recourse now - assuming you don't have one of those really really useful things called a ***backup*** - is to Google for "hard drive recovery service" & see if your data is worth more than their quote.
Prices around 100 - 1000 £$€, however there is no guarantee of what data they may be able to recover, if any.